# How to play a AES-128 encrypted HLS video in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, encryption, aes, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I'm able to play a normal HLS video in AV Player without any trouble. But how do I play a AES-128 encrypted HLS Video?

Comment: Don't you just add the access key to the headers of the request for playing?

Comment: I don't think so. But let me try!

Comment: No it doesn't work. I tried adding the decrypt key as Authorization in header

Comment: As the header in the AVURLAsset?

Comment: It worked! I actually missed the 'Bearer' keyword before the key! Thanks a lot!

Comment: glad to help :D

Comment: @Shob-Z could you give a bit more detail on how to achieve this?

Comment: I'd like some info on this too.

Comment: @nhenrique i have added the answer

Comment: @Jonny check out the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To decode an AES-128/similar encrypted HLS Video, just add 'Authorization' to your header.

```
let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx..."]
let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL, options: ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headers])
let avItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avItem)
.
.
.
```

Thanks @SeanLintern88 for helping me out on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason, it seems that this was already working, it seems that AVPlayer SHOULD be able to decrypt AES-128 encrypted streams out of the box (the key is specified in the playlist). The problem in our case was we forgot to add 0x before the IV string in the playlist. Unless I am completely wrong.

Comment: thank you very much. AVPlayer plays encrypted content out of the box indeed, the header is not required. To add another layer of security on top of HTTPS you should use cookies. Set a cookie when the user retrieves the m3u8 file and AVPlayer will automatically use that cookie on the file.key requests.

Comment: I have an encrypted video link and want to decrypt and play, tryed many ways but i cant...

Comment: This works. But sometimes the video stucks.